# Go language how detect file changing?

Tags: go

I need to know how to detect when a file changes using Go. I know that Unix provides a function named `fcntl()` which notifies when a specific file is changed but I have not found this one in Go.
Please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is currently an experimental package [here](https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify). It should be merged into core as `os/fsnotify` in go1.3

Comment: Well, it didn't make it into 1.3. Scheduled for 1.4: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4068

Comment: Link is outdated/broken

Comment: Thanks Maroshii, should be fixed now.

Comment: I've changed the URL, as the github group changed. As I was looking for this package in the standard lib, it seems like os/fsnotfy didn't make it even into go 1.6. :(

Comment: `os/notify` not in v1.8 either :-(

Comment: Doesn't look like Go standard library will be getting this anytime soon. [fsnotify](https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify) looks like the next best option as of today.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a simple cross-platform version:

```
func watchFile(filePath string) error {
    initialStat, err := os.Stat(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for {
        stat, err := os.Stat(filePath)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if stat.Size() != initialStat.Size() || stat.ModTime() != initialStat.ModTime() {
            break
        }

        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

    return nil
}
```

And usage would be like this:

```
doneChan := make(chan bool)

go func(doneChan chan bool) {
    defer func() {
        doneChan <- true
    }()

    err := watchFile("/path/to/file")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("File has been changed")
}(doneChan)

<-doneChan
```

Not as efficient as a proper system call but it's simple and works everywhere, and might be enough for some uses.

Comment: THIS. 

I simply couldnt get fsnotify to fire on subsequent file changes (as in it would only fire once) - on both macos and linux. This works for me.

Answer (score 16):

I would add to the [peterSO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221700/peterso)'s answer that if you in fact want to *read* the data appended to a file by some other process(es) — what `tail` program does in Unix, — it's probably better to just make `tail` itself do the hard job of monitoring the file and consume what it outputs.  This can be achieved by running `tail` using the `StdoutPipe` function from the [exec](http://golang.org/pkg/exec/) package.

Using `tail` for this kind of task is preferable in my eyes because `tail` has been taught to use a bunch of clever tricks including detection of file replacements (commonly occuring when one monitors a log file which is being rotated by logrotate or something similar).

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify. It wraps the inotify subsystem of the Linux kernel and should work in Go1.

Comment: This is the way forward. This package is going to be included as a standard library in Go, although the API may change.

Answer (score 6):

As of Go1 [inotify](http://golang.org/pkg/os/inotify/) has been removed from the package. Have a look at the [syscall](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#InotifyInit) package now...

> Package [inotify](http://golang.org/pkg/os/inotify/) implements a wrapper for the Linux inotify
>   system.

Comment: the link (and the package, it seems) no longer exist. Do you know where it's been moved to?

Comment: They removed it from Go Lang 1.0. You can find similar here: https://github.com/kless/go-exp/tree/master/inotify