# How to fetch input using Stdin and wait until there is new data in Stdin in Golang

Tags: go

I have a piece of code that needs to be executed every time there is new input in Stdin but the program should not terminate if there is nothing in Stdin instead it should wait for new data in Stdin and then run the computation code for that data.

How can this be achieved in Golang? Below is the piece of the code:

```
 stat, _ := os.Stdin.Stat()
 if (stat.Mode() & os.ModeCharDevice) == 0 {
      fmt.Println("data is being piped to stdin")
      scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
      for scanner.Scan() {
        text:= scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(text)
        // do some computation ....

 } else {
      fmt.Println("No data in stdin")
      // wait until there is new data in Stdin
 }
```

Can someone help me figure a way out to achieve this.

Comment: This works for most use cases. Can you show the actual problem you're having?

Comment: The problem that I am facing is that once there is no new data in Stdin, the program terminates. I need a way in which the program waits for new input in Stdin and runs the computation on that new data

Comment: How are you supplying new data once the pipe is closed? From the docs: `Scanning stops unrecoverably at EOF`. If the file descriptor is still open, make a new scanner.

Comment: Is there a way by which I can keep the pipe open? Currently I am reading the data from an input file where new lines of data would be appended periodically. I need to run the computation for each new line of data that gets appended.

Comment: No, the sender closes the pipe. That's why you need a complete example here -- I can't tell what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I have an input file from which I read the data using Stdin in this way `cat input.txt | ./test_go.go` and computation is performed for every line in the input file. I have updated my question to provide a snippet of the input file

Comment: `cat` won't stop and wait for more input, it reads the file then closes the pipe. Your go program is doing exactly what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157609/discussion-between-vasanti-and-jimb).

Comment: Why do you use stdin? If you know the file, just loop for ever, compare the modify time stamp on the file with the last time you looked, if it is newer, go to the end and read the new data. Sleep a while between two loops. Also remember how long the file was the last time, so you know where to continue reading when it changes.

Comment: I think @gonutz is right. There is a library called Tail, just like the linux tail command, aiming to do that. I have never used but you can find more information here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15328871/1775688. The project's github is https://github.com/hpcloud/tail

Comment: The input file is just an example, the actual data would be streaming in through Stdin. Thus I need a way by which my computation should be executed everytime there is new data entry in Stdin and if there is no data in Stdin my program should not terminate, instead wait until there is new data in Stdin

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `Scan` call in a loop:

```
for text := ""; text != ""; {
    for scanner.Scan() {
        text = scanner.Text()
        // ...
    }
}
```

This would have the side effect of looping even if the user puts an empty input.