# How would I read a growing file in Go?

Tags: go, tail

Just like the command `tail -f <a growing file>` ?

whenever I read a growing file, it always encounter the EOF error, and then quit.

Comment: I wound just delegate this task to `tail`, and [here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8272924/720999).  In short, reading an ever-growing file is a more complicated task that it appears on the first sight &mdash; take a look at how `tail` is implemented.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading log files as they're updated in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135738/reading-log-files-as-theyre-updated-in-go)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't experimented with it much, but there is a github repository that aims to emulate `tail` functionality in Go: https://github.com/ActiveState/tail

Comment: For my uses that tail package have worked very nicely. It is a nice API and not a lot of code so easy to work with if it doesn't do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer as if you're programming in C on Linux, then use the same/analogous options to the equivalent 'open' system call.